# livecode fullscreenmode exactfit do not work on all devices

Tags: android, fullscreen, livecode

I used the following code like it said in livecode tutorial

```
on preOpenStack
  set the fullscreenmode of me to "exactFit"
end preOpenStack
```

But when I tested my app it's not work on all devices.
For example it works on Galaxy Note 3 but on Galaxy Tab S. I can only see a small part of the app

So I change the code like this:

```
on preOpenStack
  set the fullscreenmode of Stackname to "exactFit"
end preOpenStack
```

Now it works on Galaxy Tab, but not on Galaxy Note 3

I used other `fullscreenmode` options like `letterbox` but nothing changed.

Comment: Please, provide a slightly longer code fragment, so we can see what sets the variable `Stackname`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found source of the problem.

It is the language of device.

If language of device be RTL then app dose not run correctly.

Comment: You should report this bug.

Comment: But I didn't find any solution for that.

Comment: That's the point. No solution -> bug detected -> must be reported.

Comment: I reported it last weak
Thanks for your Helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the `fullScreenMode` of a stack before opening it. Create another stack and give it the following script:

```
on openStack
  send "initialiseStack" to me in 0 millisecs
  pass openStack
end openStack

on initialiseStack
  set the fullScreenMode of stack "Your Stack" to exactFit
  go stack "Your Stack"
end initialiseStack
```

This gives LiveCode time to start up properly before opening your stack. Sometimes it provides a fix, if somehow the screen isn't drawn properly.

I don't know about any bugs that would prevent the `fullScreenMode` from working correctly on specific devices, but you may want to submit a new bug at [livecode.com](http://www.livecode.com).

Comment: Thanks but nothing changed
I used main stack and substack but none of them work
Still "this stack" work for not 3 and "stack name" work for galaxy tab S

Comment: If you provide more of the relevant code in your question, I (or we) might be able to help you better.

Comment: I testing simple app that just contain a stack and background.
I put the code that mentioned above in preopenstack 
there is not any other code